# Can you remove a random string of commas and replace with one for exporting to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I am using Netmiko to extract some data from Cisco Switches and Routers. I would like to put that data in to a spread sheet. For example show cdp neighbour would give me string with random white space in
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Et0/0                        connected    1            auto   auto unknown
Et0/1                        connected    1            auto   auto unknown
Et0/2                        connected    routed       auto   auto unknown
Et0/3                        connected    1            auto   auto unknown

I thought i could remove it and replace with , but i get this

Port,,,,,,Name,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Status,,,,,,,Vlan,,,,,,,Duplex,,Speed,Type
Et0/0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown
Et0/1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown
Et0/2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,routed,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown
Et0/3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown

Any way of extracting data like the above. Ideally to go straight in to a structured table in excel (Cells and Rows) or anyway to do what i did and then replace repeating , with just one so i can export to CSV and then import to Excel. I may be the most long winded person you have ever seen because i am so new to prgramming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with regex matches which are more flexible. You can adapt this to your needs. I put the data in a list for testing, but you could process 1 line at a time instead.

Here's the file (called mydata.txt)

```
Et0/0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown
Et0/1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown
Et0/2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,routed,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown
Et0/3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,connected,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,auto,,,auto,unknown
```

Here's how to read it and write the result to a csv file (mydata.csv)

```
import re

_re = re.compile('([^,]+)+')

newfile = open(r'mydata.csv', 'w')
with open(r'mydata.txt') as data:
   for line in data.readlines():
      newfile.write(','.join(f for f in _re.findall(line)))
newfile.close()
```

And here is the output

```
Et0/0,connected,1,auto,auto,unknown
Et0/1,connected,1,auto,auto,unknown
Et0/2,connected,routed,auto,auto,unknown
Et0/3,connected,1,auto,auto,unknown
```

Explanation:

1. The re library allows the use of regular expressions for parsing
   text. So the first line imports it.
2. The second line specifies the regular expression to extract anything
   that is not a comma, but it is only a specification. It doesn't
   actually do the extraction
3. The third line opens the output file, with 'w' specifying that we
   can write to it. The next line opens the input file. The file is
   reference by the name 'newfile'
4. The fourth line reads each line from the input file one at a time.
5. The fifth line is an all-at-once operation to separate the non-comma
   parts of the input, join them back together separated by commas, and
   write the resulting string to the output file.
6. The last line closes the output file.

Comment: First off thank you for being the first to reply to anything like this as i have never done it before :)
I am getting the information from a text file which is just the result of running the command show interface. It prints in to the console nice a neatly but i want to be able to put this in to an excel sheet seperated as you can imagine it would be

Comment: Thank you so much. Very Very Kind of you and loved the explanation. I have give it a Tick but it says it does not display as i am a Neebie. Quick question. Is this the only way to to do this. Take the information remove formatting put it a CSV type file then import to excel. if the question is to big to answer. Don't worry you have done enough :)

Comment: Don't worry - I can see the tick mark. There is another library called `openpyxl` that provides the capability to write Excel files directly. I use it quite often for reading Excel workbooks but have not used it for writing them so I don't have that requirement. Unlike `re`, `openpyxl` is not built in to Python and needs to be installed with `pip` or some other method.

Comment: Yeah thats what i am using to write the files, but with it being a string initially then i needed to split it up to put it in table form. Thanks again

Comment: Well you could change this line `newfile.write(','.join(f for f in _re.findall(line)))` and just use `_re.findall(line.strip())` because it will be a list that would be easily inserted using `openpyxl` into a worksheet. As you have a working solution I'll leave that to you - or for another question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't misunderstand you. To turn that repeating commas to one single comma, just run this code with your string s:

```
while ",," ins s:
    s = s.replace(",,", ",")
```

Comment: Please excuse my utter newness to Python. Thank you so much for replying. can this while be run on the variable itself. for example if it was 
cdp = open("cd.txt" , "r")
cdp_t = cdp.read()
cdp_t = cdp_t.replace(" " , ",") 

or is there a much better way of doing this

Comment: @dancullen s is the string you have from the file, like the example in the question. after running the while loop, you can write s back in your file.